# Line object not showing up in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I need to create some shape object like Circle, Line etc in Windows Forms using C#.
Added reference to PresentationFramework from .Net tab and using System.Windows.Shapes.
**But after creating Line object it is not showing in Windows Form.**

Please see below sample code :
code in load event of form :

```
Line myline = new Line();
myline.X1 = 100;
myline.X2 = 300;
myline.Y1 = 300;
myline.Y2 = 300;
myline.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
myline.StrokeThickness = 2;
```

Please let me know wrong I'm doing in it.

Comment: Your tag shows Winforms but you are using WPF - Which framework are you actually using?

Comment: Added reference to WPF just to use Shape class in Windows Form. I created Windows Form Application not WPF application.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to draw using Wpf on a Winform without using an `ElementHost` Container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to update the drawing request, you are just defining the line without drawing it actually

Edited:

```
public void drawmyline()
        {
            System.Drawing.Graphics example;

            // Create pen.
            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

            // Create points that define line.
            Point point1 = new Point(100, 100);
            Point point2 = new Point(400, 400);
            example = this.CreateGraphics();
            // Draw line to screen.
            example.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);

            //e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);
        }
```

then, you call your function from any place you want, for example a button click

```
private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawmyline();
        }
```

please mark as accepted if it helped you

Comment: @user1291401 don't forget `using System.Drawing;`